# isvisible() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Python Turtle Graphics Error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been working on this simple shooter game in python turtle for a few days and I've run into a error that I cannot find an answer to. 
What I want to happen is every 5 kills the player gets, an extra enemy appears. But when I get 5 kills, infinite error messages start flooding in.
The error message is: `isvisible() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
It points towards my `enemy_attack` function where I used the `isvisible()` command to test if the enemy had been shot or not in order to respawn it from another random position. Thanks for any help in advance.
I apologise for the lack of comments.

````
import turtle
import time
import random
from random import randint
game_over = False
kill_counter = 0
enemy_spawn_number = 5

def close():
    turtle.bye()

speed = 10
enemy_speed = 0.5

lives = 3
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Defend.")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("triangle")
player.color("white")
player.penup()
player.goto(0,0)

life1 = turtle.Turtle()
life1.speed(0)
life1.shape("triangle")
life1.color("yellow")
life1.penup()
life1.goto(265,-260)
life1.setheading(-90)

life2 = life1.clone()
life2.goto(240,-260)

life3 = life2.clone()
life3.goto(215,-260)

over_message = turtle.Turtle()
over_message.speed(0)
over_message.shape("square")
over_message.color("white")
over_message.penup()
over_message.goto(0,0)
over_message.ht()

killcount = over_message.clone()
killcount.goto(250,250)
killcount.ht()
killcount.write("Kill Count: 0", align="right", font=("Courier", 15, "normal"))


def go_up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(speed)

def go_right():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(speed)


def go_left():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(speed)

def go_down():
    player.setheading(-90)
    player.forward(speed)

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(close, "Escape")


collectible = turtle.Turtle()
collectible.speed(0)
collectible.shape("square")
collectible.color("blue")
collectible.penup()
collectible.goto(0,100)

bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.shape("square")
bullet.color("grey")
bullet.shapesize(0.5,1)
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup()
bullet.goto(500,500)

shooting = False
def shoot():
    global shooting
    if bullet.isvisible() == False:
        player_x = player.xcor()
        player_y = player.ycor()
        player_facing = player.heading()
        bullet.goto(player_x,player_y)
        bullet.setheading(player_facing)
        shooting = True
        bullet.showturtle()

enemies = []
enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())
for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.speed(0)
    enemy.shape("circle")
    enemy.color("red")
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.goto(0,350)

def enemy_attack():
    global game_over
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.isvisible() == True:
            enemy.setheading(enemy.towards(player))
            enemy.forward(enemy_speed)
            wn.ontimer(enemy_attack, 10)
        else:
            if game_over == False:
                rand_direction = randint(0,3)
                if rand_direction == 0:
                    x = randint(-240, 200)
                    enemy.goto(x,450)
                    enemy.st()
                    enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 1:
                    x = randint(-240, 200)
                    enemy.goto(x,-450)
                    enemy.st()
                    enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 2:
                    y = randint(-210, 210)
                    enemy.goto(-450,y)
                    enemy.st()
                    enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 3:
                    y = randint(-210, 210)
                    enemy.goto(450,y)
                    enemy.st()
                    enemy_attack()

enemy_attack()      
wn.onkey(shoot, "space")
while True:
    wn.update()

    if player.distance(collectible) < 20:
        x = randint(-290, 290)
        y = randint(-290, 290)
        collectible.goto(x,y)

    if bullet.xcor()>310 or bullet.xcor()<-310 or bullet.ycor()>310 or bullet.ycor()<-300:
        shooting = False
        bullet.hideturtle()

    if shooting == True:
        bullet.forward(0.2)

    if player.xcor()>285:
        playerX = player.xcor()
        playerX = playerX-5
        playerY = player.ycor()
        player.goto(playerX,playerY)
    elif player.xcor()<-285:
        playerX = player.xcor()
        playerX = playerX+5
        playerY = player.ycor()
        player.goto(playerX,playerY)
    elif player.ycor()>285:
        playerY = player.ycor()
        playerY = playerY-5
        playerX = player.xcor()
        player.goto(playerX,playerY)
    elif player.ycor()<-285:
        playerY = player.ycor()
        playerY = playerY+5
        playerX = player.xcor()
        player.goto(playerX,playerY)

    for enemy in enemies:
        if bullet.distance(enemy) < 20:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            enemy.goto(0,350)
            kill_counter = kill_counter+1
            killcount.clear()
            killcount.write("Kill Count: {}".format(kill_counter), align="right", font=("Courier", 15, "normal"))
            if kill_counter == enemy_spawn_number:
                enemies.append(turtle.Turtle)
                for enemy in enemies:
                        enemy.speed(0)
                        enemy.shape("circle")
                        enemy.color("red")
                        enemy.penup()
                        enemy.goto(0,350)
                enemy_spawn_number += 5

        if enemy.distance(player) < 20:
            enemy.ht()
            player.goto(0,0)
            lives = lives-1
            if lives == 2:
                life3.ht()
            elif lives == 1:
                life2.ht()
            elif lives == 0:
                life1.ht()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    if lives == 0:
        game_over = True
        collectible.ht()
        player.ht()
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.ht()
        over_message.write("Game Over! Press Esc to exit.", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))```
````

Comment: Can you share full (or at least a slightly bigger part) error information?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I would put the full error message but because it was spamming it inside Idle, I could not highlight it and copy and paste. I could only pause it and read it then type what I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problems I see are those that @furas refers to: `enemy_attack()` invokes itself both recursively and via a timer; `turtle.Turtle` is invoked without parentheses.  I don't think invoking `enemy_attack()` either way is a good idea and instead it should be invoked in the main program loop.

One problem with using `ontimer()` is that you need to make sure the timeout you use is greater than the time it takes to execute the function.  Unless it's designed to be running multiple instances of itself at the same time.  Given it writes a global, then it probably should be only one at a time.

You shouldn't have `while True:` (nor `time.sleep()`) in an event-based environment like turtle.  The `ontimer()` method should handle both.

Python-wise, you shouldn't do:

```
if bullet.isvisible() == False:
    if enemy.isvisible() == True:
        if game_over == False:
if shooting == True:
```

Instead do:

```
if not bullet.isvisible():
    if enemy.isvisible():
        if not game_over:
if shooting:
```

Below, I've taken apart your code and reassembled it the way I expect a turtle-based game to be designed.  There may be bugs still, but it seems to be playable now:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

ENEMY_SPEED = 1
PLAYER_SPEED = 4
BULLET_SPEED = 6

SMALL_FONT = ('Courier', 15, 'normal')
LARGE_FONT = ('Courier', 24, 'normal')

def go_up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(PLAYER_SPEED)

def go_right():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(PLAYER_SPEED)

def go_left():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(PLAYER_SPEED)

def go_down():
    player.setheading(-90)
    player.forward(PLAYER_SPEED)

def enemy_attack():

    for enemy in enemies:

        if enemy.isvisible():
            enemy.setheading(enemy.towards(player))
            enemy.forward(ENEMY_SPEED)
        else:
            rand_direction = randint(0, 3)

            if rand_direction == 0:
                x = randint(-240, 200)
                enemy.goto(x, 325)
            elif rand_direction == 1:
                x = randint(-240, 200)
                enemy.goto(x, -325)
            elif rand_direction == 2:
                y = randint(-210, 210)
                enemy.goto(-325, y)
            elif rand_direction == 3:
                y = randint(-210, 210)
                enemy.goto(325, y)

            enemy.showturtle()

def shoot():
    if not bullet.isvisible():
        bullet.goto(player.position())
        bullet.setheading(player.heading())
        bullet.showturtle()

kill_counter = 0
enemy_spawn_number = 5
lives = 3

def move():
    global kill_counter, enemy_spawn_number, lives

    enemy_attack()

    if player.distance(collectible) < 20:
        collectible.goto(randint(-260, 260), randint(-260, 260))

    if bullet.isvisible():
        if not (-310 < bullet.xcor() < 310 and -310 < bullet.ycor() < 310):
            bullet.hideturtle()
        else:
            bullet.forward(BULLET_SPEED)

    playerX, playerY = player.position()

    if playerX > 285:
        player.setx(playerX - 5)
    elif playerX < -285:
        player.setx(playerX + 5)
    elif playerY > 285:
        player.sety(playerY - 5)
    elif playerY < -285:
        player.sety(playerY + 5)

    for enemy in enemies:
        if bullet.isvisible() and bullet.distance(enemy) < 15:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            enemy.sety(325)

            kill_counter += 1
            killcount.clear()
            killcount.write("Kill Count: {}".format(kill_counter), align='right', font=SMALL_FONT)

            if kill_counter == enemy_spawn_number:
                enemy = enemy_prototype.clone()
                enemy.showturtle()

                enemies.append(enemy)

                for enemy in enemies:
                    enemy.sety(325)

                enemy_spawn_number += 5

        if enemy.distance(player) < 20:
            enemy.hideturtle()
            player.goto(0, 0)

            lives -= 1

            if lives == 2:
                life3.hideturtle()
            elif lives == 1:
                life2.hideturtle()
            elif lives == 0:
                life1.hideturtle()

    if lives == 0:
        collectible.hideturtle()
        player.hideturtle()

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.hideturtle()

        over_message.write("Game Over! Press Esc to exit.", align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)
    else:
        screen.ontimer(move, 70)

    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.title("Defend.")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(0)

player = Turtle()
player.shape('triangle')
player.color('white')
player.penup()

life1 = Turtle()
life1.shape('triangle')
life1.color('yellow')
life1.penup()
life1.goto(265, -260)
life1.setheading(-90)

life2 = life1.clone()
life2.goto(240, -260)

life3 = life2.clone()
life3.goto(215, -260)

over_message = Turtle()
over_message.hideturtle()
over_message.color('white')
over_message.penup()

killcount = over_message.clone()
killcount.goto(270, 270)
killcount.write("Kill Count: 0", align='right', font=SMALL_FONT)

collectible = Turtle()
collectible.shape('square')
collectible.color('blue')
collectible.penup()
collectible.goto(randint(-260, 260), randint(-260, 260))

bullet = Turtle()
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.shape('square')
bullet.shapesize(0.5, 1)
bullet.color('grey')
bullet.penup()
bullet.goto(500, 500)

enemy_prototype = Turtle()
enemy_prototype.hideturtle()
enemy_prototype.shape('circle')
enemy_prototype.color('red')
enemy_prototype.penup()
enemy_prototype.sety(325)

enemy = enemy_prototype.clone()
enemy.showturtle()

enemies = [enemy]

screen.onkeypress(go_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(go_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(screen.bye, 'Escape')
screen.onkeypress(shoot, 'space')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

The next issue I believe you should address are all the number constants in the code that prevent you from resizing the screen:

```
life1.goto(265,-260)
life2.goto(240,-260)
life3.goto(215,-260)
killcount.goto(250,250)
x = randint(-240, 200)
x = randint(-240, 200)
y = randint(-210, 210)
y = randint(-210, 210)
x = randint(-290, 290)
y = randint(-290, 290)
if bullet.xcor()>310 or bullet.xcor()<-310 or bullet.ycor()>310 or bullet.ycor()<-300:
if player.xcor()>285:
elif player.xcor()<-285:
elif player.ycor()>285:
elif player.ycor()<-285:
```

These should all be defined relative to the screen size:

```
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
```

and the objects they manipulate.  (I.e. no large numbers in the code!)

Answer (score 0):

I run code and it worked most time without problem.

At some moment it got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/furas/main.py", line 198, in <module>
    enemy.speed(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 2167, in speed
    return self._speed
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_speed'
```

and I start thinking why `enemy` (which is `turtle`) doesn't have `_speed` ? Why it treats it as integer? All `enemy` are on list `enemies` so I start checking what you add to this list and I found that you forgot `()` in one of `Turtle()`

```
enemies.append(turtle.Turtle)
```

so it added class Turtle instead of instance of Turle.

After adding `()` I don't have this error but it seems there is other problem because after 5 killed enemies it freezes. It would need some debugging (or use of `print()`) to find what is a problem.

---

**EDIT:** I have the same problem if I add two enemies at start. Problem can be that it may run two times `wn.ontimer` which may run another two `wn.ontimer` so finally it may have no time to execute them.

---

**EDIT:** Code works better if I uses only `wn.ontimer(enemy_attack, 10)` at the end of function and remove other `enemy_attack()`. But this time enemies shows mostly at the same time and when I kill one of them then it remove all of them. It may need more changes.

```
def enemy_attack():
    global game_over
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.isvisible() == True:
            enemy.setheading(enemy.towards(player))
            enemy.forward(enemy_speed)
        else:
            if game_over == False:
                rand_direction = randint(0,3)
                if rand_direction == 0:
                    x = randint(-240, 200)
                    enemy.goto(x,450)
                    enemy.st()
                    #enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 1:
                    x = randint(-240, 200)
                    enemy.goto(x,-450)
                    enemy.st()
                    #enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 2:
                    y = randint(-210, 210)
                    enemy.goto(-450,y)
                    enemy.st()
                    #enemy_attack()
                elif rand_direction == 3:
                    y = randint(-210, 210)
                    enemy.goto(450,y)
                    enemy.st()
                    #enemy_attack()

    wn.ontimer(enemy_attack, 10)
```